# Unloading classes passed via RMI

Tags: java, rmi, classloader

I have  a simple RMI 'compute' server application (similar to [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html)) that accepts objects of some interface type from clients over RMI, executes the `compute()` method of the received object and returns the result over RMI to the remote client. The jobs are 'one-offs' and there is no interaction between the different jobs or between objects of different jobs.

I would like to be able to modify classes and submit instances to the compute server for execution without constantly restarting the server JVM. However when a class that has been modified is submitted again as a parameter to a remote call it's method behaviour does not change (this occurs with anonymous classes also). I have been reading up about serialization and I realise that this is to do with the ClassLoader being unable to modify existing classes.

From my reading on SO and elsewhere I realise that somehow the ClassLoader that loaded the stream class must be GC'd and replaced in order to load a new version of my class. I have an idea how to do this but the situation seems complicated by the underlying RMI runtime and it having its own RMIClassloader.

My question is: What would be the easiest way to load each new version of a class received via RMI parameters. Ideally I'm looking for a way to have each remote call get a new ClassLoader and to dispose of it upon return. Is this feasible to do without an intricate knowledge of customised ClassLoaders and the internals of RMI?

Any pointers to reading materials or examples welcome!

Edit: here is the compute server's remote interface:

```
public interface ComputationEngine extends Remote {
    public Object execute(Task t) throws RemoteException;
}
```

and the 'compute job' interface, `Task`:

```
public interface Task extends java.io.Serializable {
    public Object compute();
}
```

Comment: It's not the the class loader needs to be GCed (although you will eventually run out of memory if it isn't). IIRC, within part of the RMI implementation there is a map from codebase to `ClassLoader`.

Comment: What are the parameters to compute()?  Are the clients sending class files that they want to execute, or are you just trying to dynamically update the implementation of the compute() interface as bugs arise without having to restart the server?

Comment: @ Tom: I was under the impression that the only way to unload classes was to GC the `ClassLoader`. From my experiments it appears that all remote calls are using the same `ClassLoader`. Thanks though, I will do more searching using those terms.

Comment: @ bkail: The clients are sending objects of custom classes (which implement `Task`) for execution. I want to be able to modify/tweak the method code of clients' 'job' classes, resubmit the job and then be able to observe the new behaviour without restarting the server JVM. Thanks :-)

Comment: A `ClassLoader` and its classes will be collected at the same time. You might be missing that you can multiple classes with the same fully-qualified name if they are loaded by different class loaded instance. (Btw, there should be no between '@' and user's name for notification to work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to this is to have a new ClassLoader when you want to change a Class.
How about making use of the URLClassLoader and making the code available from a URL

I use it in one of my projects to update APIs when the jar file changes. Take a look here:
http://code.google.com/p/open-forum/source/browse/trunk/Wiki/org/one/stone/soup/wiki/jar/manager/JarManager.java
Line 184+

Check your emails :-)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really answering your question, but it might be possible to make changing part of your classes into data instead of the actual class.  Use a `Map` instead of fields, etc.  You'd have a lot fewer classes floating around, and your code would probably be simpler too.

Comment: It's a general purpose compute server (as in the Java tutorial for RMI). Messing up data isn't going to help when it is the code that bytecode instructions that need to change.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, like Tom says though I am relying on updating the **behaviour** (i.e method code) of classes sent to the server (I've updated the question to make it clearer).